# MediaElement.js Player Spacing Gap

Tags: javascript, media-player, spacing

I've been using the PowerPress version of the MediaElement.js Player with great success however, I have one aesthetic issue.  The PowerPress settings give you the option of putting the player at the end of a post or beginning (or use a shortcode and put it anywhere).  I display the player at the end of each post.

There is a massive gap between the end of the post and the actual player.  I know it's not the theme because it does the same thing if I display the player at the top of the post (large gap on top).  How or where do I go to encase the player in a div so I can remove the large gap above the player?

[image]

I'm not a coder but have enough general knowledge that if you can point me where I should be looking at and if the div option is the best option for proper spacing between the element and end of post.  Thanks.

Comment: Right click on the player or above it, and select "Inspect Element". You'll be able to see where that margin/padding comes from, and to find out what stylesheet is responsible for this. You can then edit it to suit your needs.

Comment: @blex forget everything I've posted in response.  I don't know code.  I walked away, had dinner, chilled came back and went back in to see what I was missing and found the answer.  There are line breaks <br> between each meta entry that is causing the problem.  I played around and deleted in the element inspection and sure enough it cleared it up.  Now the problem is how to permanently remove them so this does corrects all of the podcasts.  That's where I'm stuck.  https://1e9a6aa6-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/whiwo65/home/miscellaneous/br.PNG

Answer (score 0):

PowerPress does not add <br /> tags. I've seen this happen though by other plugins that replace carriage returns with <br /> tags when h1-h5 and p tags are missing in the post content (An attempt to fix plain text in a blog post). Your best bet is to disable plugins one by one until you find the culprit.

This is all happening in the "the_content" action filter. You can add a define in your wp-config.php to tell PowerPress to add its player and links after what ever plugin is adding the <br /> tags does its modifications.

Add the following in your wp-config.php, anywhere above the require line near the bottom:

```
define('POWERPRESS_CONTENT_ACTION_PRIORITY', 99999);
```

The 99999 will make PowerPress add the player and links last (hopefully last) in the the_content action. Keep making that number larger till the problem goes away.

I've also seen plugins (though not recently) that modify the content after the page has been created. Hopefully you're not running into that situation here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was given this very same response in the Blubrry forum and it definitely works!

I had already troubleshooted the issue by disabling my plugins, but none corrected the issue.  Personally, I still think this came from Google's AdSense plugin, which parses your site to determine best placement for ads.  I could be wrong, but it seems to be the most likely cause.